# Why my Realm database is so large?

Tags: ios, realm, real-mode

The image below shows all my Realm classes and datas, but it is larger than 300MB.

I implement a save method for each RLMObject, will it case the problem?

```
- (void)save{
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [realm addObject:self];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Github thread for this issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/931

Comment: This was an issue in Realm that has since been fixed. See https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/931 for details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, saving each object in a new transaction is problematic - resource intensive and creates many many versions of Realm, and you shouldn't be doing that.

Also, you should always make sure your Realm instance is closed on background threads. In iOS, you do this with explicit `autoreleasepool {`.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the auto-refesh. It worked for me.

Hope it helps